# UIWebview Doubletap to select text

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, swift

I have created an app that displays some text on a UIWebview. I am looking to provide a functionality to the user to double tap on a particular word to select it (Selection Range should appear- which only appears when a long touch is done currently).

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIMenuController and http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html are what you are looking for.

Comment: I think You have to edit the web file plese see this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995210/disabling-user-selection-in-uiwebview

Comment: Of course I don't know what you want to do, but usually this is not a good idea. Users expect apps to behave in a certain way, for example they tap on a button and expect a reaction, they wouldn't double tap on it, because that is not how iOS usually works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `UIWebView` is flexible enough for what you want.

If all you display is rich text you should probably use `NSAttributedString` and display it using `UITextView` subclasses or one of the many [dedicated libraries](http://cocoapods.org/?q=rich%20text).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing right now. TextKit with custom pagination + UITextView.

Comment: Three years is a long time indeed ;)

Comment: Nope, the original question is not mine. That'd be too bad. :)