# Disable copy and paste menu from the textfield on a WebView. My app is based on IOS Phonegap.

Tags: ios, cordova, webview, long-press

My app is a ios phonegap application . I want to disable the copy and paste menu from the textfields on the web view. On long press and on double clicks , the copy paste menu shows up.I tried to disable long press and double clicks with UIGestureRecognizer class :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
UILongPressGestureRecognizer* longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]     initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gestureHandler:)];
[longPressGesture setMinimumPressDuration:0.2];
longPressGesture.delegate = self;
[self.webView addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
}

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer    shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer   *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]]) {
    return  NO;
    }
    else if([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]){
    return  NO;
    }
    else
        return YES;
}
```

But am not able to disable it for double clicks.Anyone with the same query?
Help me out...

Answer (score 5):

Well you have to write a category for UIWebView that overrides the canPerformAction method,

```
@implementation UIWebView (DisableCopyPaste)

-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    if (menuController) {
        [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible = NO;
    }
    return NO;
}

@end
```

import this category in your .pch file found in the xcode project folder, set break points to test whether the long press event fires this method.

FYI this method may be called many times, don't worry it is for the list of options that are available for the particular UI component that the user long presses.

For creating a category follow these steps.

**Click the add button on the bottom of your project's solution browser in Xcode.**

[image]

**Next Select Objective C Category in the options.**

[image]

**Next Select UIWebView or type UIWebView in the category for textbox and give any name to the category**
[image]

**Click Next and save the category on to your project location and copy paste the above function. Voila!.**

**For disabling copy paste or other options in text input placed in HTML see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995210/disabling-user-selection-in-uiwebview).**

Comment: Can i know , if we can create a category for a webview in phone gap. I am new to it , so have queries with phone gap.

Comment: No problem, will walk you thru.

Comment: thanks satheeshwaram for your suggestion. I am still not able to solve the problem, i still get the same copy and paste menu on  the webview

Comment: Did you import this category in your .pch file? Did the longpress action fire this event?

Comment: yes i have and the function gets hit when long press event occurs. Function returns false still the copy paste menu pops up

Comment: Oops sorry gave you the wrong function, try this function now.

Comment: i have seen this option on all ios app. Is this the behaviour of the browser/webview. Can't we disable it? My app is cordova based. I am facing issue on the webview not a view or view controller.

Comment: yes you can do it, I have tried this in a cordova + ios native hybrid app previously and found it working. If the method is being fired you are on the right direction but hiding the menu is our problem. Can you check whether the menuController object has some value during the break point?

Comment: I have tried adding this to the css -webkit-user-select: none; But this disables the input field , it doesnt take any input from the keyboard.

Comment: This works great for text inside a UIWebView.  But do you know how to control available actions for an HTML input field inside the UIWebView?

Comment: Did you check whether this method was getting called when you start editing the text input inside HTML??

Answer (score 1):

Add following css in your web page body or on page for disable selection/copy of UIWebView

```
.ui-page 
{ 
   -webkit-touch-callout: none; 
   -webkit-user-select: none; 
}
```

Comment: +1, this is a good way to do this but does not work all the time.

Comment: and also it gives some issues in ios7 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290613/disable-copy-and-paste-in-uiwebview-unsolved/12905995#12905995

Comment: this disables my input field, keyboard shows up but cannot type anything to the field

Comment: Using Crosswalk (using Blink), `-webkit-touch-callout: none` has no effect, though `-webkit-user-select: none` works fine. Shame that both of them are non-standard.

Answer (score 1):

```
  Use below code.
  <style type="text/css">
    *:not(input):not(textarea) {
       -webkit-user-select: none; /* disable selection/Copy of UIWebView */
       -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* disable the IOS popup when long-press on a link */
    }       
  </style>

  If you want Disable only anchor button tag use this.
   a {-webkit-user-select: none; /* disable selection/Copy of UIWebView */
      -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* disable the IOS popup when long-press on a link */
  }
```