# Implement cut, copy paste in uiwebview

Tags: iphone

I am implementing a text editor using uiwebview for ipad. I am using a simple javascript to Bold Italics and Underline the text.

`[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.execCommand(\"Bold\")"];`

The above code is using for making the text bold.

Now I want to implement cut, copy and paste as well. I am using this code for cut copy and paste.

`[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.execCommand(\"Cut\")"];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.execCommand(\"Copy\")"];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.execCommand(\"Paste\")"];`

But its not working. Am I using the wrong command parameter or is there any way to implement it?
I understand there is a popup menu which gives all these features but I want to disable this  popup menu and want to used of my own.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Disabling user selection in UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995210/disabling-user-selection-in-uiwebview)

here you can find disabling the copy past menu items

Thanks

Comment: I have disabled the menu items, I want to implement the copy paste into my own button similar to the menu item.