# Copy selection is more trigger happy in UIWebView for iOS6 compared to iOS5

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I'm using a UIWebView and have noticed the copy feature is much much more trigger happy in iOS 6 than in iOS 5.

If I display a web page with a small button then on iOS 5 I had no problems clicking the button, however on iOS 6 its very very easy for the OS to interpret the clicking of the button as a desire to copy the button or the whole screen and either the button, or the while UIWebView screen, or first the button then the screen gets highlighted for copying.

How can I disable this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995210/disabling-user-selection-in-uiwebview).

The top answer given is very thorough and should be of use to you.