# How to disable a standard double tap gesture on UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview, gestures

How to disable a standard double tap gesture on `UIWebView`? But all other gestures should continue to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look to the my answer, part 2 on the question: [Disabling user selection in UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995210/disabling-user-selection-in-uiwebview)