# How to remove selection from UIWebview?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

In my iPhone app,I am using a web view in a view controller.
When I press and hold the screen,some selections come on webview, at times a action sheet comes which has "copy" and "cancel" buttons

How to remove this ?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995210/disabling-user-selection-in-uiwebview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can disable the selection by using this code

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.webkitTouchCallout='none'; document.body.style.KhtmlUserSelect='none'"];
```

if you using Jscript in your web page then this could do the trick

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();"];
```

if you want to disable copy paste then this could do the trick

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender 
{    
    if (action == @selector(copy:) ||
        action == @selector(select:)||
        action == @selector(paste:)||
        action == @selector(cut:)) 
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

OR

```
 webView.userInteractionEnabled=NO; // in case you need to disable whole UIWebView
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .css, you can add these to the appropriate style

```
    *.noselect {
            -webkit-user-select:none;
            -webkit-touch-callout:none;
    }
```