# Remove text selection from PhoneGap iOS app

Tags: ios, cordova

I am trying to find a way to be able to restrict text selection within the entire PhoneGap application. Anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995210/disabling-user-selection-in-uiwebview

Answer (score 6):

this will work for you:-

```
<style type="text/css">
   *:not(input):not(textarea) {
   -webkit-user-select: none; /* disable selection/Copy of UIWebView */
   -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* disable the IOS popup when long-press on a link */
  }     
</style>
```

Using java script:-

```
 document.documentElement.style.webkitTouchCallout = "none";
 document.documentElement.style.webkitUserSelect = "none";
```

Answer (score 5):

```
html {
-webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

this little ingredient in your css code will do the magic!

Comment: I used this response along with @Suhas -webkit-touch-callout and it works great... vote for both...

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 9 there is a bug which makes the `-webkit-user-select: none;` not work. There is a plugin which fixes this

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-ios-longpress-fix

Thanks to Frederik Wessberg https://stackoverflow.com/a/32737049/741850

Comment: Thanks this solved it. How ever since the plugin does not do that much you might wanna consider just copying the implementation.