# global disable magnifying glass on iOS 9 in meteor cordova app

Tags: css, cordova, meteor, aero-glass, loupe

[image: iOS9_glass]

I have tested several workarounds to disable the annoying magnifying glass with css, but on my iOS9 meteor cordova build it appears for a moment and fades out after some ms.

it was working on iOS 8 but not on iOS 9 now with this css code:

```
body, body * {
    -webkit-user-select: none !important;
    user-select: none !important;
    -webkit-user-callout: none !important;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none !important;
}
input, textarea {
    -webkit-user-select: text !important;
    user-select: text !important;
    -webkit-user-callout: default !important;
    -webkit-touch-callout: default !important;
}
*{
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox all */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10+ */
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    -webkit-user-modify: none;
}
```

I missed something for iOS 9?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IOs Cordova long-press shows text-select magnifying glass even with text-selection disabled, how to remove?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32812308/ios-cordova-long-press-shows-text-select-magnifying-glass-even-with-text-selecti)

Comment: looks like I was first

Comment: The fix is no longer working in iOS 15.1. See https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/1216

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin Frederik mentioned is now build into cordova see https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/pull/174

To enable the fix insert `<preference name="SuppressesLongPressGesture" value="true" />` into `config.xml`

Comment: This is no longer working in iOS 15.1. See https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/1216

Comment: Let's hope the upstream fix mentioned in that issue will fix it 

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it is related to iOS9.
Since you are a Cordova user, this plugin will fix the problem for you:
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-ios-longpress-fix

It has to do with the UILongPressGestureRecognizer executing before handling the -webkit-user-select: none in your css.

I hope this helps you out.

Comment: be aware that answers with just links are removed, somebody might report and it will be deleted (it happens to me al the time), better change it to a comment or put the plugin code on the answer

Comment: If we don't use Cordova , is there any solution ?

Comment: this plugin is outdated now with meteor 1.3 because its not using web view anymore