# IOs Cordova long-press shows text-select magnifying glass even with text-selection disabled, how to remove?

Tags: ios, css, cordova, textselection

I have a very weird problem. In my cordova app on iOS I am getting a pop-up text-select magnifying glass when I long-press anywhere in the app.

Example:

[image: Screenshot showing the select-popover]

The bubble at the top is locked to the top of the screen, and follow my x-position when moving my finger from side to side.

I have tried to add the following css which people say should fix my issue:

```
* {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

This does not help. Looking at things in the web-inspector, I can confirm that this css is successfully added to everything. I have tried a bunch of different variation of the normal `touch-callout: none` and `user-select: none` everyone suggest and nothing seem to help.

I have also tried to remove all javascript and all CSS except a simple variation of the above mentioned, and the magnifying glass still appears.

**How can I get it to go away? Is there any plugin that can be causing this issue? Any help is much appreciated.**

Cordova plugins:

- com.mbppower.camerapreview
- cordova-plugin-statusbar
- cordova-plugin-whitelist
- ionic-plugin-keyboard
- org.apache.cordova.camera
- org.apache.cordova.console
- org.apache.cordova.device
- org.apache.cordova.dialogs
- org.apache.cordova.file
- org.apache.cordova.file-transfer
- org.apache.cordova.network-information
- org.apache.cordova.vibration

Cordova version: 5.1.1
iPhone 5s with iOS version: 9.0.1

Comment: possible duplicate of [global disable magnifying glass on iOS 9 in meteor cordova app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32720848/global-disable-magnifying-glass-on-ios-9-in-meteor-cordova-app)

Comment: @jcesarmobile I found that later too, but that was only after a lot of googling for various things.

Comment: The fix is no longer working in iOS 15.1. See https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/1216

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thank you for that Automatico! Saved me from a lot more frustration.

Since then however it looks like that code has been merged into mainline cordova and can just be enabled by adding

`<preference name="SuppressesLongPressGesture" value="true" />` to config.xml

That worked perfectly for me!

Here is the commit and notes that brought it in

https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/commit/1ad9951c80dbf97281e763f5f27a9bc8852c0537

Comment: Thank you! This should be the accepted answer now. To confuse matters even more, I don't see the magnifying bubble on an iphone 6 plus, but I do see it on 6 and the simulator.

Comment: This is definitly working on iOS 11. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This is no longer working on iOS 15.1, due to a regression bug in WebKit. See https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/1216

Answer (score 6):

Apparently, in iOS 9 there is a bug which makes the `-webkit-user-select: none;` not work. There is a plugin which fixes this

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-ios-longpress-fix

Thanks to Frederik Wessberg https://stackoverflow.com/a/32737049/741850