# IBM Worklight 6.0 - How to disable copy/paste options of the MainView/WebView?

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to disable copy/cut menu of text area to prevent export any data from application.  I put following code in `apps/<AppName>/iphone/native/Classes/CDVMainViewController.m` file, but it didn't work. It seems canPerformAction is called when a menu appears, but cut/copy actions are not passed to this code.

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
  BOOL can = [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
  if (action == @selector(cut:) || action == @selector(copy:))
  {
    can = NO;
  }
  NSLog(@"%@ for action:%@ from sender:%@.",
    can ? @"YES" : @"NO", NSStringFromSelector(action), sender);
  return can;
}
```

How can I disable these options?

Comment: Did you look at other questions and answers for alternate implementations? See here: https://www.google.com/search?q=ios+disable+copy+paste&oq=ios+disable+copy+paste

Comment: The answer is given here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995210/disabling-user-selection-in-uiwebview

Comment: Thanks Anton. With Swizzle method (in Altaveron's reply of the entry), I've done what I wanted. By the way, why didn't my previous code work in Worklight? Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Takakiyo, is this question resolved?

Answer (score 0):

As Anton pointed out in the comments area of the question, have a look at this question for possible solutions: [Disabling user selection in UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995210/disabling-user-selection-in-uiwebview)

Here are a couple from it:

Via CSS:

```
  textarea {
      -webkit-touch-callout: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none; /* Disable selection/copy in UIWebView */
  }
```

Via native code (although I believe this may not be specific to the textarea, but rather to the whole app screen; but you can modify that):

```
 - (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender 
    {    
        if (action == @selector(copy:) ||
            action == @selector(paste:)||
            action == @selector(cut:)) 
        {
            return _copyCutAndPasteEnabled;
        }
        return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
    }
```