# Disable Cut/Copy in Webview

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview

OK, the scenario is simple:

- I have a WebView
- I want the user **not to** be able to cut/copy anything from that webview, no matter what  (either with <kbd>⌘C</kbd>, or via the Edit menu)

I know I have to subclass WebView, but which specific methods do I have to override?

Any ideas? (Any other approach is welcome!)

Answer (score 4):

Add the following CSS to some file

```
html {
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
}

body {
    -webkit-user-select: none !important;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none !important;
}
```

And link that CSS to your HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="LayoutTemplates/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
</html>
```

Or programmatically disable it

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView 
{
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.style.webkitUserSelect='none';"];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.style.webkitTouchCallout='none';"];
}
```

Comment: Hmm... I've seen a similar answer, like 100 times, but it most definitely has no effect at all. I can perfectly go inside the Webview, pick some text and Cmd+Copy it, or use the Edit menu... (I really have no idea what is going on, or why what supposedly works for others, doesn't work for me!)

Comment: that's strange, first solution is now working on my project, if there is no selection, you can't copy it. How you're trying to copy it?

Comment: Cmd+C and **Edit** > **Copy** both work. The thing is (perhaps because my situation has some twist), I want to block/intercept the `copy:` and `cut:` actions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995210/disabling-user-selection-in-uiwebview "Disable the Copy / Paste user menu:" also doesn't work?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. `canPerformAction:` is never getting called (I believe someone mentioned its purpose is to check for JS-triggered actions only... :S)

Comment: You need to swizzle `-[UIWebDocumentView canPerformAction:]` with that one, did you?

Comment: Just found the answer. I'm posting it right now ! :-)

Answer (score 3):

OK, here's the solution.

First, set the Webview's Editing Delegate:

```
[_myWebview setEditingDelegate:self];
```

Then implement the one function we need in order to intercept the copy/cut actions (or any action for that matter, but that's what we're going to do anyway):

```
- (BOOL)webView:(WebView *)webView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)command
{
    NSString* commandStr = NSStringFromSelector(command);

    if ( ([commandStr isEqualToString:@"copy:"]) || 
         ([commandStr isEqualToString:@"cut:"]))
    {
        NSPasteboard *pasteboard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
        [pasteboard clearContents];
        return YES; // YES as in "Yes, I've handled the command, 
                    // = don't do anything else" :-)
    }
    else return NO;
}
```

I hope you won't waste as much time as I did looking for a valid answer... :-)

Comment: @l0gg3r Thanks, I've been banging my head against the wall for hours... :-)