# iOS Safari HTML button and angular Click

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, meteor

So, I'm working on a web app, and one of the features is holding a button down to increase or decrease a value.

Right now the app is backed with Meteor.js running Angular as the front end. And my functionality works great, except on Mobile Safari. Any time a user tries to hold down the button, OR tap the button in rapid succession, iOs brings up the magnifying glass and tries to select some random text on the page.

Any ideas how to fix this? My google fu has return `-webkit-user-select: none;` but that doesn't seem to fix my issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling user selection in UIWebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995210/disabling-user-selection-in-uiwebview)

Answer (score 0):

It should work:

```
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
```

> behaviour, i.e., the callout never shows up on tapping and holding.
>   By using -webkit-touch-callout: none; you can prevent this default behaviour, i.e., the callout never shows up on tapping and holding.

http://codetheory.in/list-of-webkit-css-properties-for-mobiles/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @PetroKorienev To me it seems very much like an answer. Just because it contains a question mark doesnt mean it is not an answer.

Comment: @Anders please, take a look at answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6051172/2392973 on the same topic - and learn how it's contented and formatted. Your post is rather a comment, because it's like a thrown-in-space advice, without descriptive background, explanation of why it works etc.

Comment: @PetroKorienev It is not my answer. I am not saying it is a good answer - I don't know much about the subject, so I could not say - I am just saying it is an *attempt to answer the question*. If you think it is a *bad answer*, you should downvote and not flag.