# How to disable copy share option while selecting text in uiwebview? But selecting text should work

Tags: ios, uiwebview, selection, copy-paste

I want to restrict user from copying and sharing text in `UIWebView`.

The code i'm using is

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.webview.delegate = self;
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SampleHTML" ofType:@"html"];
NSString *htmlContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[self.webview loadHTMLString:htmlContent baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
```

}

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
if (action == @selector(copy:))
return NO;

else if (action == @selector(select:))
return YES;

return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is add new class with subclass of UIWEBVIEW.

Paste this code in .m file of your class.

```
@implementation UIWebView (Additional)

- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    BOOL superCanPerform = [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
    if (superCanPerform) {
        if (action == @selector(copy:) ||
            action == @selector(paste:)||
            action == @selector(cut:)||
            action == @selector(_share:))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return superCanPerform;
}
```

Try this out and this will hide all the submenu required.

Answer (score 0):

Try with code, This works for me

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView 
{
     [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.style.webkitTouchCallout='none';"];
}
```

To Disable Sharing,

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender { 
if (action == @selector(customMethod:)) {
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
return NO;
}
```

Hope this Works for you.

Comment: I want to have selection option working, only copy and share i want to disable.

Comment: Check Now :) You will also get more option from here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995210/disabling-user-selection-in-uiwebview

Comment: No it is still allowing user to copy the text inuiwebview.

Comment: No its not working here. I have taken sample html and called in uiwebview. I have edited my code above.

Comment: I have added your code too in this, but not performing.