# How to disable text selection WKWebView programatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

**Problem**

You can select text in the **WK**WebView.

**Desired Behaviour**

You should not be able to select text in the webview at all.

**What I've tried**

1. Loading `NSString * jsCallBack = @"window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();";` using `evaluateJavaScript:completionHandler:`
2. doing the above using `"document.documentElement.style.webkitUserSelect='none'"`
3. `webView.configuration.selectionGranularity = nil;` <-- This one doesn't make sense as `selectionGranularity` can only take two predefined values, but it was worth a try.
4. Tried looking for a solution inside the storyboard, couldn't find a solution that wouldn't disable user interactions.

**What I can not do**

Changing the HTML/CSS code is not an option at this time, if I could change it [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6051172/7105550) would probably work.

Comment: I shared some details on inner details of how selection works internally in `WKWebView` in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49437716/5329717 I'll have a proper look at your case eventually.

Answer (score 0):

**Semi private gray area** solution relying on private web views hierarchy and its tap gestures. As a bonus doesn't rely on private class & method symbols, but if order of tap gestures would change it would break.

```
@import WebKit;
@interface ViewController ()

@property(null_resettable, nonatomic,strong) WKWebView *view;
@end

@implementation ViewController

@dynamic view;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view = [WKWebView new];

    for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
        for (UIView *innerView in view.subviews) {
            if (innerView.gestureRecognizers.count > 0) {
                NSMutableArray<UIGestureRecognizer*> *gestureRecognizers = [innerView.gestureRecognizers mutableCopy];
                [gestureRecognizers removeObjectAtIndex:0];
                innerView.gestureRecognizers = [gestureRecognizers copy];
            }
        }
    }

    [self.view loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43227437/how-to-disable-text-selection-wkwebview-programatically"]]];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**// add gesture on viewDidLoad**
override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let longPress:UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: nil, action: nil)
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.3
    webView.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
}

**//also inherit the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate**

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).