# How to change the text selection color in WKWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, webkit, wkwebview

I'm trying to change text selection color in `WKWebView`. I tried pretty much all the solutions proposed for `UIWebView`/`WKWebView` that I was able to find.

Changing tint color does not work. Applying css for `::selection`, `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` tags works neither.

[image]

It's always blue. Is it possible to change it?

Comment: may be this will help you.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28642485/is-it-possible-to-change-text-selection-color-in-uiwebview-ios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of iOS 13, setting WKWebView's `tintColor` property also changes the selection color (and the caret color).

```
WKWebView *webView = ...
webView.tintColor = UIColor.redColor;
```

Extra tip: if you have an app that has dark mode support but for some reason the WKWebView content must be light mode, you can either force the whole view controller containing the WKWebView to have the light mode trait or you can do:

```
if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
    webView.tintColor = [webView.tintColor resolvedColorWithTraitCollection:[UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithUserInterfaceStyle:UIUserInterfaceStyleLight]];
}
```

this ensures that the selection and caret colors will be visible with "light" content in the html

Answer (score 2):

Here's the sample code for it.

```
function highlight(colour) {
var range, sel;
if (window.getSelection) {
    // IE9 and non-IE
    try {
        if (!document.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour)) {
            makeEditableAndHighlight(colour);
        }
    } catch (ex) {
        makeEditableAndHighlight(colour)
    }
} else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
    // IE <= 8 case
    range = document.selection.createRange();
    range.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour);
}}
```

call this method by Objective-C code

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"highlight('#ff0')"];
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here's my shot at **private WebKit API hacky swizzling** obviously **not eligible** for an AppStore app. Apple happens to provide lots of open source code for it:
https://opensource.apple.com/source/WebKit2/WebKit2-7601.1.46.9/UIProcess/ios/WKContentViewInteraction.h.auto.html
https://opensource.apple.com/source/WebKit2/WebKit2-7601.1.46.9/UIProcess/ios/WKContentViewInteraction.mm.auto.html

So the actual selection highlight for html content happens in 2 phases. Until the tap is being held on the touch screen **private class** `UIWKSelectionView` is shown. The highlight happens to be its `tintView` property. Each `tintView` getter call generates a new `UIView` instance with highlight color as the background. So the override needs to happen after each access.

In the second phase (after user releases the tap) the selected range is represented by **private class** `UIWebTextRangeView`. The text vertical markers with dots are `UIWebDragDotView`. The highlighting happens in `updateRectViews` method , which needs to be called before doing the color overriding.

The final solution is **validated** for **iOS 8 - 11**, once the color is overriden it will affect all `WKWebView` instances. The original highlight color is hardcoded in `UIWKSelectionView` & `UIWebTextRangeView` and fetched through **UIKit private method** `+[UIColor selectionHighlightColor]` which yields `RGBA 0 0.33 0.65 0.2`.

The actual code (I chose `obj-c` for swizzling convenience but this could also be done in `Swift`):

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@import WebKit;
static IMP __original_Method_IMP_tintView;
static IMP __original_Method_IMP_updateRectViews;

//UIWebTextRangeView
void replacement_updateRectViews(UIView* self, SEL _cmd)
{
    ((void(*)(id,SEL))__original_Method_IMP_updateRectViews)(self, _cmd);
    for (UIView* view in self.subviews) {
        //isMemberOfClass would be used instead to filter out UIWebDragDotView if its color is meant to be unchanged
        if ([view isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UIWebDragDotView")]) {
            [view setValue:UIColor.redColor forKey:@"m_selectionBarColor"];
        } else {
            //These are UIView*
            view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.2];
        }
    }
}

//UIWKSelectionView
UIView* replacement_tintView(id self, SEL _cmd)
{
    UIView* tintView = ((UIView*(*)(id,SEL))__original_Method_IMP_tintView)(self, _cmd);
    tintView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.2]; 
    return tintView;
}

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController
+ (void)load {
    __original_Method_IMP_tintView = method_setImplementation(class_getInstanceMethod(NSClassFromString(@"UIWKSelectionView"),NSSelectorFromString(@"tintView")), (IMP)replacement_tintView);
    __original_Method_IMP_updateRectViews = method_setImplementation(class_getInstanceMethod(NSClassFromString(@"UIWebTextRangeView"),NSSelectorFromString(@"updateRectViews")), (IMP)replacement_updateRectViews);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view = [WKWebView new];
    [(WKWebView*)self.view loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://stackoverflow.com/"]]];
}
@end
```