# How to get rid of annoying gray-highlight effect when pressing buttons on IPhone

Tags: html, css

I have the following very basic `HTML` code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">
* {
    outline: none;
}
a {
    padding: 6px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
    border-radius: 6px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 100px;
}
a:active {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #b9b9b9;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #b9b9b9;
}

</style>
<title>IPhone - Button</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#">Long Press This</a>
</body>
</html>
```

and when I open it on a real `IPhone` device I get the following:

[image]

but when I long press the button I get the following:

[image]

with that very annoying gray-highlighted background.

I get that annoying effect only on IPhone. I tried the same on the rest of browsers (Android, Windows, MacOS) without getting that effect.

Any idea on how to get rid of that?

Here you have an inline demo of the code:

```css
* {
 outline: none;
}
a {
 padding: 6px 20px;
 border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
 border-radius: 6px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 40px;
}
a:active {
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #b9b9b9;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #b9b9b9;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Long Press This</a>
```

Please, notice that I need that `box-shadow` above at the same time I get rid of the gray highlight. In other words, I need the same effect I get on the rest of browsers.

Here it is also on `JSFiddle.net`:

http://jsfiddle.net/05kqt7m3/

http://jsfiddle.net/05kqt7m3/embedded/result/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
<style type="text/css">
* {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Disable selection/copy in UIWebView */
}
</style>
```

As shown in [Disabling user selection in UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995210/disabling-user-selection-in-uiwebview#6051172)

Comment: I just tried that but unfortunately didn't work. Any other idea?