# How to prevent iOS Webkit long press on link?

Tags: ios, swift, webkit

Im trying to disable the long press on webKit to not let the user Save or Copy in Swift 4.

This is the code im using:

```
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.body.style.webkitTouchCallout='none';")
```

I have seen some other answer in objective-c

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.webkitTouchCallout='none';"];
```

but converting it to swift it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: _" it doesn't work."_… what happens? Doesn't compile? Error? Wrong result?

Comment: It compiles good, Open the page but its still let me Long touch an image and try to save it or copy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling user selection in UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995210/disabling-user-selection-in-uiwebview)

Comment: @Bilonik welcome to SO...the above answer lists a number of possible solutions that may work, including intercepting the long press with your own long press gesture. Take a look and see if something works!

Comment: Thanks, BJHStudios but i have try all those solutions. Im running IOS 12 with Xcode 10 and its still letting me Long press and copy, share , open....

Comment: By adding `UILongPressGestureRecognizer ` to `webView`, it shouldn't allow copy/share etc. Did you try that?

Comment: @Kamran had try    let longPress:UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: nil, action: nil)
            longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.2
            self.webview.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
   Still cant disable the save

Answer (score 1):

There is a property called allowsLinkPreview with that you can enable or disable the long touch previews.

```
 webView.allowsLinkPreview = false
```