# WKWebView selection haptics when selection is turned off

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

When you select text in Safari (and WKWebView), there is a haptic feedback. I disabled *any selection* (see code below) on the page I'm opening in WKWebView, and the haptic feedback is still there when I long press anywhere on the WKWebView. How can I disable it?

```css
    * {
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
    }
```

Comment: Have you found a solution? Having the same problem.

Comment: @marco-a unfortunately not :(

Comment: I have found something, that might work, I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having the same issue and I found something that seems to work just fine:

```
let longPress:UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: nil, action: nil)
longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.2
webView.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
```

Taken from [Disabling user selection in UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45238660/2005038).

Comment: This works great for a single tap, but doesn't work for a double tap held down unless you set `minimumPressDuration = 0.1` (don't ask me why)