# How to disable Copy and Paste (callout/popup) in WKWebView?

Tags: javascript, css, ios, xamarin.ios, wkwebview

I want to disable the callout menu, which pops up if you long tap an element in the web view:

[image: Cut, copy, paste, look up, share]

There are many answers out there like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6051172/426227), but neither of them seems to work. Don't know if the things for `UIWebView` are also valid for `WKWebView` ...

I tried to manipulate the CSS via JavaScript. This seems only work if you add your scripts to the `WKUserContentController` and not on [`didFinish()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455629-webview).

Things, which do not work:

```js
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
document.body.style.webkitTouchCallout='none';
document.body.style.webkitUserSelect='none';
```

Things, which partly work:

```js
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.innerHTML = '* { -webkit-touch-callout: none; -webkit-user-select: none; }';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
```

Or in CSS form

```css
*:not(input):not(textarea) {
    -webkit-user-select: none;    /* disable selection/copy of UIWebView */
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;  /* disable the iOS popup when long-press on a link */
}
```

Only things like `*` or `*:not(input):not(textarea)` seems to work (no `body` or another specific tag). The problem with this is, that so many elements are disabled through this ... I would need this on some specific elements only!

I also tried to use [`canPerformAction()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621105-canperformaction):

```cs
private static readonly Selector copyAction = new Selector("copy:");
private static readonly Selector pasteAction = new Selector("paste:");
private static readonly Selector cutAction = new Selector("cut:");

public override bool CanPerform(Selector action, NSObject withSender)
{
    if (action == copyAction || action == pasteAction || action == cutAction)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(action.Name);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Here it seems another responder in the chain is returning true and overwriting my settings. The popup/callout menu still appears. I was only to minimize the available options (as seen in the screen above).

The only thing I could try is to work with gesture recognizers to disable such taps, but currently I have no idea how.

What can I do to disable the popup/callout menu?

Comment: Try to open the webview in Safari to check if the issue still exists . You could also share the sample so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: OK I'll make some tests and if I find something I'll let you know. Which sample do you need? The Xamarin one, the web page or both? I can't really give you the web page, but you can try [this link](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview) and long tap the "Action" button with an iPhone (iOS 14) device. This should simulate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried overriding the method canPerformAction which is working well in UIWebView, but it does not work on WKWebView.

```
    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.cut(_:)) ||
        action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.copy(_:)) ||
        action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.selectAll(_:)) ||
        action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.select(_:)) {
        return false
    }
    return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
}
```